# How to open a web page without the browser following embedded links?

Tags: firefox, html, links

I am trying to open some older web pages (from 2010) which evidently are trying to load some graphics from a remote source that no longer exists. So the web page hangs on load until the download times out. Is there any way of opening the page so these links are ignored. I only want the text from within the page.

My first choice browser is Firefox Quantum.

Comment: Can you see the texts from the page source?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Eventually, yes. Afer the timeout when it fails to fetch graphics.

Answer (score 1):

> **I only want the text from within the page**

You could try using a text mode browser such as [Lynx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser))

This should not fetch linked images or JavaScript resources